# Scrapy: TypeError: __init__() missing 1 required positional argument: 'url'

Tags: python, selenium, scrapy

I'm trying out a scrapy package https://github.com/clemfromspace/scrapy-selenium.

I've followed the directions on the main github page above. I started a new scrapy project and created a spider:

```
from scrapy_selenium import SeleniumRequest

from shutil import which

SELENIUM_DRIVER_NAME = 'firefox'
# SELENIUM_DRIVER_EXECUTABLE_PATH = which('chromedriver')
SELENIUM_DRIVER_EXECUTABLE_PATH = which('geckodriver')
SELENIUM_DRIVER_ARGUMENTS=['-headless']  # '--headless' if using chrome instead of firefox

USER_AGENT = 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:48.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/48.0'


class MySpider(scrapy.Spider):

    start_urls = ["http://yahoo.com"]
    name = 'test'


    def start_requests(self):
        for url in self.start_urls:

            yield SeleniumRequest(url, self.parse_index_page)


    def parse_index_page(self, response):
        ....
```

The output:

```
 'scrapy.extensions.telnet.TelnetConsole',
 'scrapy.extensions.logstats.LogStats']
2019-07-05 14:14:44 [scrapy.middleware] WARNING: Disabled SeleniumMiddleware: SELENIUM_DRIVER_NAME and SELENIUM_DRIVER_EXECUTABLE_PATH must be set
2019-07-05 14:14:44 [scrapy.middleware] INFO: Enabled downloader middlewares:
['scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.robotstxt.RobotsTxtMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.httpauth.HttpAuthMiddleware',
 ........
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.httpproxy.HttpProxyMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.stats.DownloaderStats']
2019-07-05 14:14:44 [scrapy.middleware] INFO: Enabled spider middlewares:
['scrapy.spidermiddlewares.httperror.HttpErrorMiddleware',
 'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.offsite.OffsiteMiddleware',
 'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.referer.RefererMiddleware',
 'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.urllength.UrlLengthMiddleware',
 'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.depth.DepthMiddleware']
2019-07-05 14:14:44 [scrapy.middleware] INFO: Enabled item pipelines:
[]
2019-07-05 14:14:44 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Spider opened
2019-07-05 14:14:44 [scrapy.extensions.logstats] INFO: Crawled 0 pages (at 0 pages/min), scraped 0 items (at 0 items/min)
2019-07-05 14:14:44 [scrapy.extensions.telnet] INFO: Telnet console listening on 127.0.0.1:6023
2019-07-05 14:14:44 [scrapy.core.engine] ERROR: Error while obtaining start requests
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "....\splashtest\lib\site-packages\scrapy\core\engine.py", line 127, in _next_request
    request = next(slot.start_requests)
  File "E:\ENVS\r3\scrapySelenium\scrapySelenium\spiders\test.py", line 55, in start_requests
    yield SeleniumRequest(url, self.parse_index_page)
  File "....\splashtest\lib\site-packages\scrapy_selenium\http.py", line 32, in __init__
    super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
TypeError: __init__() missing 1 required positional argument: 'url'
2019-07-05 14:14:44 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Closing spider (finished)
2019-07-05 14:14:44 [scrapy.statscollectors] INFO: Dumping Scrapy stats:
{'finish_reason': 'finished',
 'finish_time': datetime.datetime(2019, 7, 5, 18, 14, 44, 74274),
 'log_count/ERROR': 1,
 'log_count/INFO': 9,
 'log_count/WARNING': 1,
 'start_time': datetime.datetime(2019, 7, 5, 18, 14, 44, 66256)}
2019-07-05 14:14:44 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Spider closed (finished)
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the link in the question, the `scrapy_selenium.SeleniumRequest` constructor takes initial arguments `wait_time`, `wait_until`, `screenshot`, and `script`, passing any remaining arguments along to the `scrapy.Request` constructor.

The posted code instantiates a `SeleniumRequest` with two positional arguments, which means that no arguments will be passed to the `Request` constructor, causing the error in question.

To fix this, you can either explicitly pass the default `SeleniumRequest` arguments by position:

```
yield SeleniumRequest(None, None, False, None, url, self.parse_index_page)
```

or pass the `Request` arguments by keyword (generally a better style, both because it's resilient against changes to the default arguments and because it's far easier to determine what's going on):

```
yield SeleniumRequest(url=url, callback=self.parse_index_page)
```

Comment: Thanks Craig , I used the second, which worked. Just for my own information, looking at: class SeleniumRequest(Request):
    """Scrapy ``Request`` subclass providing additional arguments"""

    def __init__(self, wait_time=None, wait_until=None, screenshot=False, script=None, *args, **kwargs): Is it true that the "*args, **kwargs" are based to the base class - in this case scrapy's Request class ?

Comment: @user61629 At the end of `SeleniumRequest`'s constructor it calls `Request`'s constructor like this: `super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)` (the `self` argument is already bound by `super` in python 3). That's what passes those arguments along to the base class' constructor.